# what's wrong with my fiddle using jqueryui selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable

hi I have a very simple fiddle to understand how to use jqueryui selectable:

http://jsfiddle.net/hvqz7/.

However it doesn't look work. Anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line in the CSS should be:

```
#container .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/U8XsX/

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is wrong.

Change this:

```
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

To this:

```
#container .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x26My/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Mistake in there was because of this class you added

```
#selected .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }​
```

It should be `#container .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }​` instead

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hvqz7/3/)